# Load Web API data to 'Slug' on 'View' page within .NET Core App?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api-design

I am having a hard time figure out how I can dynamically open slug within my .NET Core 2.2 Web. This is how my API deliver the data from slug via JSON API request:

```
/api/books/how-to-become-a-millionaire


/api/books/10-features-a-successful-entrepreneur
```

Above are two examples of `slug` I receive from API, now I would like it render on a webpage, once I hit the URL with:

`https://mybookswebsite.com/books/10-features-a-successful-entreprenuer`

It should work for all `slug` URLs. So, I can open all books URLs via slug. My main concern is knowing, how could I make the last part of the api endpoint `/10-features-a-successful-entreprenuer` assumed as the string should be used to extract and rendered to the page.

How this can be done within client-side view in my WebApp?

Comment: Any buddy needs clarification?

Comment: Yes please. I need clarification. Also, can you show me a sample of your web api method to get the book using the slug?